# HEX to Float JS file I have I need to Convert Hex to UNIT32 anyone can suggest what should I need to made

Tags: javascript

I Need to convert HEX (String to subsring )data into UNIT32 please suggest the correct formatting
below I prepared one JS file for the HEX to Float Conversion for reference & its working,Kindly advise what change should I need to do for the UNIT32 Conversion

```html
var str = '0x3F160008';

function parseFloat(str) {
    var float = 0, sign, order, mantiss,exp,
    int = 0, multi = 1;
    if (/^0x/.exec(str)) {
        int = parseInt(str,16);
    }else{
        for (var i = str.length -1; i >=0; i -= 1) {
            if (str.charCodeAt(i)>255) {
                console.log('Wrong string parametr'); 
                return false;
            }
            int += str.charCodeAt(i) * multi;
            multi *= 256;
        }
    }
    sign = (int>>>31)?-1:1;
    exp = (int >>> 23 & 0xff) - 127;
    mantissa = ((int & 0x7fffff) + 0x800000).toString(2);
    for (i=0; i<mantissa.length; i+=1){
        float += parseInt(mantissa[i])? Math.pow(2,exp):0;
        exp--;
    }
    return float*sign;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is in a format that's compatible with the built-in `parseInt`, just use it directly:

```js
console.log(parseInt('0x3F160008'));
```

Or if you prefer, remove the prefix and tell `parseInt` you're parsing hex:

```js
console.log(parseInt('0x3F160008'.substring(2), 16));
```

Comment: @GaganBarjatya - I have no idea what that comment is supposed to tell me.

Comment: First of all Thank you so much for your response

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder can you please write the script I believe I am doing mistake in it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
// // Convert Hex value to float.
function main(a1) {
var b1 = a1;
var d1= b1.substring(4,12);
    var int = parseInt(d1, 16);
    if (int > 0 || int < 0) {
        var sign = (int >>> 31) ? -1 : 1;
        var exp = (int >>> 23 & 0xff) - 127;
        var mantissa = ((int & 0x7fffff) + 0x800000).toString(2);
        var float32 = 0
        for (i = 0; i < mantissa.length; i += 1) { float32 += parseInt(mantissa[i]) ? Math.pow(2, exp) : 0; exp-- }
        var c = float32 * sign;
        }
   else c=0;
return c;
}
```

Can I make changes in this JS file@T.J. Crowder